# Whats the difference between (concat [x] y) and (cons x y)?

Tags: clojure

I am stuck at the [Pascal's Trapezoid](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/147) from 4Clojure site, where you need to build a lazy sequence of the  trapezoid's numbers.

My first shot was this:

```
(defn pascal [x]
  (cons x
   (lazy-seq
    (pascal 
     (map +
        (cons 0 x)
        (conj x 0)      
      )))))
```

Which didn't work:

```
user=> (take 5 (pascal [1 1]))
([1 1] (1 2 1) (0 2 4 2) (0 0 4 8 4) (0 0 0 8 16 8))
```

Writing it this way works, however:

```
(defn pascal2 [x]
  (cons x
   (lazy-seq
    (pascal2
     (map +
        (concat [0] x)
        (concat x [0])      
      )))))

user=> (take 5 (pascal2 [1 1]))
([1 1] (1 2 1) (1 3 3 1) (1 4 6 4 1) (1 5 10 10 5 1))
```

So, what exactly am I doing wrong here? What is the difference between cons/conj and concat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others stated `conj` inserts the element(s) it receives in a different position depending on the concrete collection type, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008411/clojure-seq-cons-vs-list-conj) SO question for more detailed information about the difference between `conj` and `cons`.

In the first version of your `pascal` function you are providing a vector as the initial argument so the expression `(conj x 0)` will insert the `0` at the end of the vector for the computation of the second element in the series, **but** since map returns a lazy sequence, when the third element is computed the insertion happens at the beginning (`(conj (map inc '(0)) 2) ;= (2 1)`), which results in wrong elements in the series from then on.

In order to use the `cons` and `conj` approach you have to make sure you return a vector by using `mapv` instead of `map`.

```
(defn pascal [x]
  (cons x
   (lazy-seq
    (pascal 
     (mapv +
        (cons 0 x)
        (conj x 0))))))

(take 5 (pascal [1 1]))

;= ([1 1] [1 2 1] [1 3 3 1] [1 4 6 4 1] [1 5 10 10 5 1])
```

The drawback with `mapv` is that it is eager so it will compute all members in the pascal element, instead of just holding it back until you actually need them.

On the other hand, when using `concat` you do ensure you append the element at the end and that everything is lazy, but the append is not done cheaply like with vectors, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734435/put-an-element-to-the-tail-of-a-collection) for more information.

Regardless of these factors you can still use `cons` in both cases, since what it does is what you need in either case (i.e. have an element inserted at the beginning of a collection).

```
(defn pascal2 [x]
  (cons x
   (lazy-seq
    (pascal2
     (map +
        (cons 0 x) ; Replaced concat with cons
        (concat x [0]))))))

(take 5 (pascal2 [1 1]))

;= ([1 1] (1 2 1) (1 3 3 1) (1 4 6 4 1) (1 5 10 10 5 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very clear now why the result is wrong. Now I just need to find the reason for conj's behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

According to [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/)

### conj

```
conj clojure.core

(conj coll x)
(conj coll x & xs)
```

> conj[oin]. Returns a new collection with the xs 'added'. (conj nil
>   item) returns (item). The 'addition' may happen at different 'places'
>   depending on the concrete type.

`conj` accepts the first argument as a collection, which means `coll` must be a collection type. `conj` will return a new collection with `x` added into `coll`, and the place of `x` added is depending on the type of `coll`.

e.g.

```
> (conj [1] [0])
 [1 [0]] ; See [0] is added into [1] as an element. Instead of returning [1 0], it returns [1 [0]]
> (conj [1] 0)
 [1 0]
> (conj '(1) 0)
 (0 1) ;See the element `0` position is different in each case.
```

### concat

```
concat clojure.core
(concat)
(concat x)
(concat x y)
(concat x y & zs)
```

> Returns a lazy seq representing the concatenation of the elements in
>   the supplied colls.

`concat` accepts all the argument as collection types, which is different from `conj`. `concat` returns the concatenation of arguments.

e.g.

```
> (concat [0] [1])
(0 1)
> (concat [0] [[1]])
(0 [1])
> (concat [0] 1) ;See the second argument is not a collection type, thus the function throws an exception.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
>
```

### cons

```
cons clojure.core 
(cons x seq)
```

> Returns a new seq where x is the first element and seq is the rest.

The doc of `cons` states clearly how `cons` would work. The second argument of `cons` must be a `seq`.

e.g.

```
> (cons [1] [0])
([1] 0) ; [1] is the first element and (0) is the rest
> (first (cons [1] [0]))
[1]
> (rest (cons [1] [0]))
(0)
> (cons 1 [0]) ; 1 is the first element and (0) is the rest
(1 0)
> (cons [1] 0) ;the second argument is not a seq, throwing exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
```

Comment: That teaches me to read the docs a bit more carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`conj` on a `list` adds the element to the front of the list. 
If you convert the list to a vector it will work.

```
user=> (conj '(1 2 3) 4)
(4 1 2 3)
user=> (conj [1 2 3] 4)
[1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, very to the point. Any idea of why this is?

Edit: Ah, there it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910673/difference-in-behavior-of-conj-on-vectors-and-lists-in-clojure